# PHP input in a new div on form submit

Tags: php, arraylist

I want to add a new todo div on my page by every submit except empty.
but some how, $todoList[] = $newItem; is not adding the new item in the array?

It is replacing the item in the div, but i want to add it.

This is my code;

```
<?php
$todoList = ["Add a Task"]; // Initialize an empty array

// Check GET method
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    // Check user-input is set and is not empty
    if (isset($_GET['user-input']) && !empty($_GET['user-input'])) {
        // make variable newItem with value of user-input
        $newItem = htmlspecialchars($_GET['user-input'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        
        // Add the new item to the todoList array.
        $todoList[] = $newItem;

        // Check the contents of the todoList array
        echo "New Item Added: " . $newItem . "<br>";
        echo "Todo List Contents:<br>";
        var_dump($todoList);
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="user-input" placeholder="Add a task">
        <button type="submit">Toevoegen</button>
    </form>

    <div class="todoList">
        <?php
        // Output the todo list items
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($todoList); $i++) {
            $item = $todoList[$i];
            echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</div>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

have tried it like this as well:

```
<?php
        // Output the todo list items
        foreach ($todoList as $item){
            echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</div>";
        }
        ?>
```

But not working, can someone point me in the right direction.
Thx,
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code is structured means, that the same PHP file gets called on the form reloads without passing the current existing values back to the code.

This means each time the script is submitted it refreshes the page and restarts all the code including the initialization of the array. So at any time you would always only have 1 item in the list.

You could rewrite the script such that the form submit will also submit the existing list items along as inputs.

However, an easier method is to use `$_SESSSION` variables to store the list, the session maintains the values across page refreshes and you would be able to retrieve all the values.

I have created a sample here with your code, where I have replaced your `$todoList` variable with the `$_SESSION` equivalents and added necessary checks.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['todoList'])){ // Check if todoList is previously initialized
    $_SESSION['todoList'] = array(); // Initialize an empty array
    $_SESSION['todoList'][] = "Add a Task"; 
}

// Check GET method
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    // Check user-input is set and is not empty
    if (isset($_GET['user-input']) && !empty($_GET['user-input'])) {
        // make variable newItem with value of user-input
        $newItem = htmlspecialchars($_GET['user-input'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        
        // Add the new item to the todoList array.
        $_SESSION['todoList'][] = $newItem;

        // Check the contents of the todoList array
        echo "New Item Added: " . $newItem . "<br>";
        echo "Todo List Contents:<br>";
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="user-input" placeholder="Add a task">
        <button type="submit">Toevoegen</button>
    </form>

    <div class="todoList">
        <?php
        // Output the todo list items
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['todoList']); $i++) {
            $item = $_SESSION['todoList'][$i];
            echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</div>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I will dive into it further.

Comment: I have though a question. Did you mean with this "You could rewrite the script such that the form submit will also submit the existing list items along as inputs." the use of the hidden input field attribute? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Brango yes, you can create a hidden input with all your tasks, since they are just strings, you can have a single hidden input with all the items as a concatenated string. 
Which you can expand in PHP.

Another option is to use Ajax for posting to PHP code, in that case, you can use javascript to fetch all the current items and pass that as data to the Ajax call.

Comment: Also, it would be much appreciated if you could mark the answer as a solution, if it was helpful and resolved the problem appropriately, I will be happy to edit and expand the answer if you need more help on this.

Comment: Is it checked now as solved? I marked the green mark checkbox on the left. Thanks for your help!